# how to write a powershell script to extract an .iso files and copy it to folders by creating folders

Tags: powershell

I have written a powershell script to downloaded from a website an iso file, now after downloading I want to mount it to the drive and extract the files/folders from that iso to a specific folder

Comment: Try [Mount-DiskImage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/storage/mount-diskimage?view=win10-ps)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simple with winrar (rarlabs.com):

& 'C:\Program Files\WinRAR\winRar.exe' @('x','C:\YourISOFile.iso','C:\TargetFolder') | Out-Null